# Functions calling without being called

Tags: python-3.x

Using the Raspberry Pi 3B+, and new to Python. I know I use globals, and would like to know what I should use instead. Sorry if I didn't make it small, but I have no idea at all what the error is, so I can't recreate it... At least answer what the error is if you know and how I could fix it, please.

Code here:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
from sys import exit
from signal import pause

print('Objective: Push the button as fast as you can when the LED goes off.')
print('First to five wins.')
left_name = input('Left player name is? ')
right_name = input('Right player name is? ')

led = LED(4)
leftscore = 0
rightscore = 0
addnum = 1
winnum = 5
right_button = Button(15)
left_button = Button(14)

def scoreleft(ls):
    ls = ls + addnum
    print(left_name + ' has ' + str(ls) + ' points!')

    if ls == winnum:
        print(left_name + ' won the whole game!')
        exit()

    else:
        print('No one has won yet...')

    return ls

def pressedleft(button):
    if button.pin.number == 14:
        global leftscore
        print(left_name + ' won this round!')
        scoreleft(leftscore)
        led.off()

def scoreright(rs):
    rs = rs + addnum
    print(right_name + ' has ' + str(rs) + ' points!')
    if rightscore == winnum:
        print(right_name + ' won the whole game!')
        exit()

    else:
        print('No one has won yet...')

    return rs

def pressedright(button):
    if button.pin.number == 15:
        global rightscore
        print(right_name + ' won this round!')
        scoreright(rightscore)
        led.off()

while True:
    led.off()
    sleep(uniform(5, 10))
    led.on()

    right_button.when_pressed = pressedright(right_button)

    left_button.when_pressed = pressedleft(left_button)

    sleep(3)
```

Shell errors: (Never touched a button. No errors, just text. It shouldn't say both were pressed at a time and the same score each time.)

```
Objective: Push the button as fast as you can when the LED goes off.
First to five wins.
Left player name is? Left player
Right player name is? Right player
Right player won this round!
Right player has 1 points!
No one has won yet...
Left player won this round!
Left player has 1 points!
No one has won yet...
Right player won this round!
Right player has 1 points!
No one has won yet...
Left player won this round!
Left player has 1 points!
No one has won yet...
```

Please use the answer feature instead of commenting, so I can give you reputation. Thank you for reading this, and any answers would be greatly appreciated. You're cool.

Comment: When you call `right_button.when_pressed = pressedright(right_button)` you are actually calling the function `pressedright()`. You need to only pass the function. `right_button.when_pressed = pressedright`. See FAQ 9.2: http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: Thank you **Mark_M** You sure you don't want rep?